# ASCIIDOC: "Unresolved directive in...": "<stdin>" "or "index.adoc"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, asciidoc

I am new to ASCIIDOC and just wanted to know WHERE the following problem comes from.

Setup:

- Intellij with the neweset ASCIIDOC-Plugin
- neweset asciidoctor-maven-plugin with `preserveDirectories = true`

I organized my asciidocs like this:

- footer.adoc
- header.adoc
- index.adoc
- subfolder

  - index.adoc

generated-docs looks like this:

- footer.html
- header.html
- index.html
- subfolder

  - index.html

Now, if I want the subfolder/index.html to include header & footer too, I thought I need to write `include::../header.adoc[]` into the adoc-file which is no problem for the Intellij-Plugin. But in the generated html you will find following error:

```
<p>Unresolved directive in index.adoc - include::../header.adoc[]</p>
```

So when I write the following into the adoc-file: `include::header.adoc[]` the generated html is happy but the Intellij ASCIIDOC plugin shows an error:

`Unresolved directive in <stdin> - include::header.adoc[]`

I am just wondering if this is a bug for the Intellij Plugin-Team or for the Maven-Plugin-Team. Or maybe someone has a workaround this problem?

And a little bonus question: Is it possible to configure the maven plugin to not generate header-/footer.htmls since they are already included into the actual htmls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with the Maven plugin, but I do have lots of experience with AsciiDoc, the IntelliJ Plugin and the Gradle plugin.

The IntelliJ Plugin behaviour is correct. When you convert `/subfolder/index.adoc`, the includes are resolved relative to this file, so the include `include::../header.adoc` is correct.

You describe that you don't specify which file to render for the Maven plugin (`header.adoc` is converted). This might be the problem with the Maven plugin:

You just specify the source path and all documents are rendered relative to this source path and hence the `/subfolder/index.adoc` has the wrong source path.

With the Gradle plugin, you can specify all documents to be converted. This would also avoid getting `header.adoc` converted. From the Maven plugin docs I see that you can specify only a single file.

With this in mind, I would suggest to change your file structure in such a way that you have all the files to be converted in one folder. You can then specify this folder and the other files should not be converted. This also should resolve your problem with the relative path name:

```
/src/docs/
      |
      +-common/
      |    |
      |    +-header.adoc
      |    +-footer.adoc
      +-chapters/
      +-main/
         |
         +-index1.adoc
         +-index2.adoc
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, the answer is found in the documentation in the restdoc manual from Spring.io in the "Using the Snippets" section of https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-restdocs/  There is some mention of this in the sample gradle project

The maven plugin configuration should be something like this:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>output-html</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceHighlighter>coderay</sourceHighlighter>
                        <backend>html</backend>
                        <attributes>
                            <toc/>
                            <linkcss>false</linkcss>
                            <snippets>
                                ${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets
                            </snippets>
                        </attributes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```